# In AES decryption, "Given final block not properly padded" occurred

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I'm doing a simple encryption file transfer system and now stopped by a run time exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:811)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:676)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:313)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2087)
    at ftpclient.FTPClient.main(FTPClient.java:82)
```

I tried to debug my code using a string to encrypt and decrypt with the same key and it works. However, when I tried to transfer stream from the file, this exception always comes.

Here are the codes of both sides. At first they will exchange symmetric key (AES key) via RSA and then transfer large files via AES encryption. We can focus on the last part of each code where the files are encrypted and decrypted by AES key.

Server Side:

```
package ftpserver;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.crypto.*;
import java.security.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64; 
/**
 *
 * @author Han
 */
public class FTPServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        //generate symmetric key and initialize cipher for AES
        SecretKey skey = null;
        Cipher aes = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");

        KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        kg.init(128);
        skey = kg.generateKey();

        //get public key of the receive side
        final String PUBLIC_KEY_PATH = "key_b.public";
        PublicKey publickey = null;
        try {
        FileInputStream fis;
        fis = new FileInputStream(PUBLIC_KEY_PATH);
        ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        publickey = (PublicKey) oin.readObject();
        oin.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        };

        //encrypte symmetric key with own private key and send out
        Cipher rsa = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        rsa.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publickey);
        byte cipherSKey[] = rsa.doFinal(skey.getEncoded());
        //System.out.println(skey); //debug

    //create tcp server socket
        ServerSocket tcp = new ServerSocket(2000);
        Socket client = tcp.accept();

        //get input&output stream from the TCP connection
        InputStream in = client.getInputStream();
    OutputStream out = client.getOutputStream();

        //generate a file input stream to get stream from file
    File sentFile = new File("F:\\test.txt");
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(sentFile);

        //send encrypted symmetric key first
        out.write("Symmetric Key:\r\n".getBytes());
        out.write(cipherSKey);

        DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(in);
        while(true)
        {
            if(din.readLine().equals("Received."))
            {
                System.out.println("Send key successfully.");
                break;
            }

        };

        //send files
    int count;
        byte[] bytearray = new byte[8192];
        byte[] cipherbuffer;
        while((count = fin.read(bytearray))>0)
    {
        cipherbuffer = Base64.encodeBase64(aes.doFinal(bytearray));
        out.write(cipherbuffer,0,cipherbuffer.length);
        System.out.println(count+" bytes have been sent.");
        };

        out.flush();
        out.close();

        client.close();


        }
}
```

Client Side:

```
package ftpclient;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
/**
 *
 * @author Han
 */
public class FTPClient {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
            //get the private key of this side


        final String PUBLIC_KEY_PATH = "key_b.privat";
        PrivateKey privatkey = null;
        try {
        FileInputStream fis;
        fis = new FileInputStream(PUBLIC_KEY_PATH);
        ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        privatkey = (PrivateKey) oin.readObject();
        oin.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        };

        Cipher rsa = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        rsa.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privatkey);

        //create tcp client socket
        Socket tcp = new Socket("192.168.1.185",2000);        
    InputStream in = tcp.getInputStream();
        OutputStream out = tcp.getOutputStream();
        DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(in);

        //receive symmetric key from server
        byte keybuffer[] = new byte[128];
        SecretKey skey = null;

        while(true)
        {
            if(din.readLine().equals("Symmetric Key:"))
            {
                System.out.println("Start to receiving key...");
                in.read(keybuffer);
                byte[] skeycode = rsa.doFinal(keybuffer);
                skey = new SecretKeySpec(skeycode, 0, skeycode.length, "AES");
                out.write("Received.\r\n".getBytes());
                break;
            }
        };
        //create cipher for symmetric decryption
        Cipher aes = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        aes.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skey);
        //System.out.println(skey); //debug

        //create file stream
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("E:\\test_cp.txt");

    int count;
        int i = 0;
        byte[] bytearray = new byte[8192];
        byte[] buffer;
        while((count = in.read(bytearray)) > 0)
        {
            buffer = (aes.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(bytearray)));
                        fos.write(buffer,0,buffer.length);   
                        i +=count;
                        System.out.println(i+" bytes have been received.");
        };


        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        in.close();

        tcp.close();
        System.out.println("File Transfer completed");

    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, you mean I should change the algorithm of cipher? Does it help to fix this bug?

Comment: no, it won't fix this.  it's just a bad idea to use ecb - see the wikipedia article on cipher modes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are calling `doFinal` multiple times.  or at least trying to.

when you read data, not all data arrives or is read into the buffer at once.  so you decrypt some and then read again.  that is all ok.

but when you do that, you are calling `doFinal` each time, instead of `update`.  this is wrong and is the cause of the error.  instead, replace `doFinal` with `update` and then add an extra `doFinal` once you have finished reading all data (there is a `doFinal()` that takes no arguments for exactly this reason).

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html

also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29 for why ecb mode is often not a good idea (look at the penguin pictures).

Comment: Thank you very much Andrew :) Using update really helped to let the whole program run, however at the end when calling doFinal(), new exception occurred:"Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher". And I tried to transfer some big files such as a video with over 100MB and after transfer, it cannot be opened properly. I found that doFinal() is meant to add Padding. So should I encode this padding also to Base64?

Comment: Oh I think the problem now is when calling doFinal() (with no parameters), it may generate something but cannot be transferred to the remote side, isn't it? So what I can do is only to call doFinal for the last part of the whole file I'm sending. doFinal() (with no parameters) actually has nothing to do with this file transfer case. Is that right?

Comment: sorry, i had forgotten about the sending side.  you need to send everything, including what is returned from doFinal, but you can call the doFinal(data...) method if that helps.  or just use update in the loop and then a final doFinal afterwards - just remember that doFinal may (will!) return data and that data must be transferred.

Comment: Thanks. I sent the return byte array of doFinal() to remote side and there is still the same problem. So should I use the Base64 encoding and decoding or not? Does it matter?

Comment: no, encoding should not matter.  you most likely just have a bug - not flushing something, or not reading correctly from the socket, or similar.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for your useful comments. I will debug it further tomorrow and update here after it works.

Comment: thanks.  with a large file try printing just the last few (encrypted) bytes and checking that you are receiving them the same.  or split your code into smaller functions and then connect them so that the output from one is written to an array of bytes and then read by the other, without the socket.  if that works get sockets working with normal text.

Comment: OH - one other thing.  i would personally avoid using `in` after using `din`.  it's not clear to me that `in` will work correctly.  perhaps `din` requested more data than it used, for example.  so i would replace `in` with `din` in later calls.  you can read bye[] from `din` too.